# Changing data in jsp using ajax

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, jsp

I have jsp page with tag "select". I want to change data at this page depending on the "option".

Here is my code:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>

<select id="select_city">
<c:forEach items="${allCities}" var="city">
    <option value="${city.name}">${city.name}</option>
</c:forEach>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#select_city').change(function() {
    $.get("/admin/users/workers?city="+$(this).val(), function(allUsers,status){
        console.log(allUsers);
    });
});
 </script>  

 </body>
 </html>
```

Controller works fine.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/users/workers", method =    RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public ModelAndView getWorkersAdmin(@RequestParam(value = "city", required = false) String city) {

 List<User> users=userRepository.findUserByCity(city);
 .... 
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    mav.setViewName("hello");
    mav.addObject("allUsers", users);
    return mav;}
```

Console.log shows me all necessary info. 
So, how to put my java-script answer to:

```
<c:forEach items="${allUsers}" var="user">
```

to update info.

Answer (score 0):

You can add options with javascript:

```
var select_city = document.getElementById('select_city');
select_city.options[select_city.options.length] = new Option('Option 1', 'value1');
```

You can iterate your "allUsers" in ajax success callback, and add options as above in your loop.

Answer (score 0):

More of a comment than an answer, but the space is needed.

You are missing the point, when the JSP page is requested it generates the HTML. The JSP will not be executed again until the page is requested again, and then it will generate the whole place again.

So, no, you cannot use the JSP tag to fill the select with Ajax. The JSP is executed in the server, you want to use JavaScript (which is executed in the web browser, with the HTML that has been downloaded) to deal with Ajax. With JavaScript, you may alter the HTML contents (which are organized in a DOM structure) to clean the previous values from the select and all the new values that you receive through the Ajax call.

So, you have to modify your javascript function to do that (retrieve the select by ID, delete its contents and load the new ones).

Comment: Thanks) It was useful)